# Hybrid Application Development in Sitecore

Tags: jquery, html, sitecore

Can we develop Hybrid Applications with Sitecore using HTML5 And Jquery ?
I have found the Javascript API for Sitecore , but it basically deals with the website development in Sitecore using Javascript and accessing the native Features of the device.
Additionally we do have Android and iOS SDKs also for Native Development.
But do we have any way out for Hybrid Applications as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this, you just have to change your perception of "presentation". Under most models, you develop a website back ended by Sitecore. The templates are your data model, layouts and sub-layouts are your presentation logic.

Nothing is stopping you from creating MVC controllers with actions that return JSON based on data obtained from Sitecore (in versions after 6.6 you do have to do a bit of work to make sure url routes go to your controller and not Sitecore.) The benefit to this is your front-end logic is consuming a specialized data transfer object as opposed to trying to transform native Sitecore objects into something usable. The big challenge is many of your controller actions are going to need to take Sitecore id's as parameters to aid in retrieving information from the Sitecore database.

I've taken this approach on several projects, where the "fixed" landscape of the website was built using "traditional" Sitecore techniques, and JQuery AJAX calls got JSON from MVS controller actions that we're then bound to HTML templates (either JQuery templates, or other libraries such as Handlebars)

Comment: can you share any concrete example explaing the same. So that i can take the reference and understand the way out in a better manner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sitecore 6.5 you can use the [Sitecore Item Web API 1.0](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf). If you are using 6.6 and higher you can use the [Sitecore Item Web API 1.2](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc66-71-usletter.pdf). Also you can always develop your own services on top of sitecore and use them in your Hybrid Applications.

Comment: So sitecore will be handling only the database part ? cant we develop any client side Front End of any Hybrid Applications by Sitecore , like we can do for Native Android and iOS development through SDK provided by Sitecore

Comment: @Learner I don`t think I understand the question entirely. You can get the items with the API. What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a perception that Sitecore is used for developing Websites and keep them updated through the content Management System , that it offers. (Correct me if i am wrong). Also it offers Android and iOS SDKs for the development of Native Applications . Does it offers anything to develop a Hybrid Application ( not website ) using HTML5 , Jquery along with sitecore environment ?

Comment: @Lerner - You are right that Sitecore is a Content Management System. Also this is the first time I have seen the SDKs, but as it seems that there are such SDKs and they are using the Item Web API (as I saw here: https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-ios-sdk-sample). So I guess the Web API mentioned in my answer is exactly what you are looking for !

Comment: Yeah i agree The Javascript API , u are saying ! But that again is used for the development of Websites only and not Hybrid Applications , as far as i have searched. But i am looking for the Development of Hybrid Applications( through HTML5 , Jquery ) with Sitecore . Can you share what exactly is the role of Sitecore cause i am purely looking into the development part for the Applications.

Comment: @Learner the role will be that you will have Content Management System for your data and you can also manage them via the API. What role exactly do you expect from Sitecore ? Isn`t hybrid application you are talking to (I am guessing you want to wrap it in phonegap or something) all about evaluating data from backend API ? You have full control over the sitecore items (create,update,delete etc) if you want to do some kind of management in your hybrid app. If you give me a solid example of what exactly do you try to achieve I might be more helpful.

Comment: Yeah u got it right, something like in collabration with Phonegap , so that i can develop it in HTML Jquery and Could be packaged with Phonegap and used with sitecore along. Okay i will try figuring out some kinda example and let you know and can have your feedback over the same . Thanks @nsgocev